# If triangle's angles are $\alpha \leq \beta \leq \gamma$, then respective opposite sides are $a \leq b \leq c$. How to handle obtuse case?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, proof-writing, triangles

> Knowing that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are the lengths of the sides opposite to (respective) angles $\alpha \le \beta \le \gamma$, prove that $a\le b \le c$.

I use the Law of Sines: $$a = 2R\sin(\alpha) $$ $$b = 2R\sin(\beta) $$ $$c= 2R\sin(\gamma)$$ 
Now, I subsitute these values into the initial inequality and divide by $2R$:
$$\sin(\alpha) \le \sin(\beta) \le \sin(\gamma) $$

> As for an acute triangle, it works great, but how do I prove that this inequality holds for — for example — an obtuse triangle?

Comment: What does $R$ mean here?

Comment: The radius of the circumscribed circle.

Comment: @amWhy The mention of the law of sines *seems* to make clear that $\;R=$ the radius of the circumscribing circle.

Comment: @ILoveChess It must be the **circumscribing** circle, not the circumscribed one...

Comment: @DonAntonio, is there any difference between a circumscribing and a circumscribed circle? I have never come across the gerund form.

Comment: @ILoveChess IMO circumscribed circle is incircle.

Comment: @ILoveChess Perhaps it is a language barrier, but "circumscribing" is, for me, from circumscircle = the circle that *surrounds* a triangle in such a manner that the triangle's three vertices are on the circle, and *circumscribed* means (again, for me) the circle **inside** the triangle and such that the triangle's sides are "tangent" to it. Its center is the intersection of the three angles' bisectors.

Comment: So, @DonAntonio, it was a relevant comment afterall!  Particularly after your comment.  What we can conclude is that $\frac a{\sin \alpha} = \frac b{\sin \beta} = \frac c{\sin \gamma}$

Comment: What about "inscribed" and "circumscribed"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle

Comment: @amWhy Of course. What you wrote is **precisely** the law of sines, and each expression equals the diameter of the circumcircle.

Comment: @DonAntonio I think the circle tangent to the three sides is normally called the inscribed circle, or the incircle.

Comment: @ILoveChess Yes, perhaps inscribed is the correct form. As mentioned, it may have been a language problem (for me, of course).

Comment: @Chappers That seems to be the current (and correct) use, indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My original answer was inadequate. Try this:

We have the angles $\alpha<\beta<\gamma$. If all are acute, your analysis applies, because the sine is increasing in $[0,\pi/2]$.

If not all are acute, then only $\gamma$ is obtuse, and since $\gamma+\beta<\pi$, we also have $\beta<\pi-\gamma$, both acute. Then, by your argument, we have $\sin\alpha<\sin\beta<\sin(\pi-\gamma)$. Since $\sin\gamma=\sin(\pi-\gamma)$, the result $a<b<c$ follows in this case as well.

Comment: If $\gamma$ is obtuse, then $\beta$ and $\alpha$ are acute. Is it always obvious that the sine of this obtuse angle will be greater than the sine of the acute angles?

Comment: Sorry, this was a too-partial or inadequate answer. I'm away from my keyboard now, will correct and expand soon